# Is it possible to search by Realname?

Tags: 7, users, search

I have the Realname module installed to display the real name of my users in my database rather than the name. ie realname Bob smith however name is bsmith. However the search box only looks for name or email. So when users search by Real Name somethings nothings appears. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

On another page I have a view of the contacts and an exposed filter to search by realname but I want to keep the search box in the header and have the functionally to search users and also news items etc.

Comment: Are you using Profile2 module?

Comment: No I'm using Real Name https://www.drupal.org/project/realname. Is Profile 2 better?

Comment: I'm just wondering where is the real name will came from what field I mean. Coz in Profile2 you can create a field to extend the info about the user.